# Cannot resolve method success.unapply when working with a Future[Unit]

Tags: scala, future

I'm trying to execute some code in a Future, which persists some data to a REST endpoint, which, itself makes a DB call. I'm trying to execute it in a Future so it doesn't hold up the other code around it, which may be time-sensitive. I don't really care what happens in the Future code if it's successful, so I'm trying to execute a Future[Unit]. However, when I try to write the following code, IntelliJ underlines my `Success(_)` saying

> cannot resolve method success.unapply

Here's my code:

```
def persistProgress():Unit = {
    val result:Future[Unit] = Future {
      //API Rest Call here with a case class
    }
    result.onComplete {
      case Success (_) => // do nothing if successful
      case Failure(e) => logger.info("Unable to persist" + e.getMessage)
    }

}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: In this specific case, what about [`.failed.foreach(...)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/concurrent/Future.html#failed:scala.concurrent.Future[Throwable])?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you build with the Scala compiler, directly or via sbt? Does the error really say `success.unapply` or is it `Success.unapply`? I think you'd get a different error if not, but you've definitely imported `Success`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you get proper imports? Particularly that `Success` and `Failure` come from `Try` i.e. `scala.util.Success` and `scala.util.Failure`. Your code with proper imports seems to work Ok as you can see [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1CxjsYxSTWaz6HN871ICYw).

Answer (score 1):

You might have imported `Success` twice in your code which made reference to success ambiguous.
In my case, I had imported below two lines:

```scala
import akka.actor.Status.Success
import scala.util.Success
```

Just try to run your code, the error will help to debug.